# jersey+springboot can't response correct http status

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jersey

I am using jersey + spring-boot to create my web application. When a http request makes my application throw a runtime exception, the client side always gets a 404(NOT Found) error. I assume that it should return 505(Internal Error) code but why it always return 404 code. In addition, when the exception happens, I will get below log in my server side. Could you let me know what wrong with my application? How should I debug it?

```
o.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent  : A servlet request to the URI http://localhost:8080/error contains form parameters in the request body but the request body has been consumed by the servlet or a servlet filter accessing the request parameters. Only resource methods using @FormParam will work as expected. Resource methods consuming the request body by other means will not work as expected.
```

Comment: would you just add code, to understand ur question more?

Comment: Looks like you're sending url-encoded form params but trying to read the request's body in some other way - also possible it got directed to a wrong resource. Post your code